# Implement OpenIDConnect for Flutter Web with the PKCE scheme

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I want to use Keycloak for my login with the PKCE scheme. I use the following package https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client On Android it works perfectly. But on web it uses the implicit flow but it needs to be the PKCE scheme. I found the following article https://medium.com/@rangika123.kanchana/keycloak-integration-for-flutter-web-using-openid-client-with-authorization-code-flow-489afeac6e9f and implemented the code as shown below. It opens up the Keycloak page where I can login. But the code does not wait and I can't get the credentials. Also when I click on login again I dont get the credentials. Also when I press the login button I get an error.
Does any body have an idea on how to solve this?
As said I use Keycloak but what I want is only a access token and the name, email nothing more. Is there maybe an other way?

```dart
  String _randomString(int length) {
    var r = Random.secure();
    var chars =
        '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    return Iterable.generate(length, (_) => chars[r.nextInt(chars.length)])
        .join();
  }

  Future<Credential?> authenticateWeb(
    Client client, {
    List<String> scopes = const [],
  }) async {
    var codeVerifier =
        html.window.sessionStorage["auth_code_verifier"] ?? _randomString(50);
    var state = html.window.sessionStorage["auth_state"] ?? _randomString(20);
    var responseUrl = html.window.sessionStorage["auth_callback_response_url"];
    print("responseUrl: $responseUrl");

    var flow = Flow.authorizationCodeWithPKCE(
      client,
      scopes: scopes,
      codeVerifier: codeVerifier,
      state: state,
    );

    flow.redirectUri = Uri.parse(
        '${html.window.location.protocol}//${html.window.location.host}${html.window.location.pathname}');

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

    if (responseUrl != null) {
      // handle callback
      try {
        var responseUri = Uri.parse(responseUrl);
        var credentials = await flow.callback(responseUri.queryParameters);
        return credentials;
      } finally {
        html.window.sessionStorage.remove("auth_code_verifier");
        html.window.sessionStorage.remove("auth_callback_response_url");
        html.window.sessionStorage.remove("auth_state");
      }
    } else {
      // redirect to auth server
      html.window.sessionStorage["auth_code_verifier"] = codeVerifier;
      html.window.sessionStorage["auth_state"] = state;
      var authorizationUrl = flow.authenticationUri;
      html.window.location.href = authorizationUrl.toString();
      print(authorizationUrl.toString());
      var responseUri = flow.redirectUri;
      var credentials = await flow.callback(responseUri.queryParameters);
      print("Redirecting to authentication server...");
      return credentials;
    }

    // var authenticator = browser.Authenticator(
    //   client,
    //   scopes: scopes,
    // );
  }
```

```
responseUrl: null

https://keycloak.XXX.de/auth/realms/production/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&scope=openid+email+offline_access+roles+profile&client_id=XXX-public&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2F&state=IkAh95HTvCqF6KvYZE2w&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=rOc5rai8V0yb6ipktf5wEJDLOKNZmciyQA_x6L-IaUc

Error: Invalid argument(s): State does not match

at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:4200/dart_sdk.js:5679:11)

at openid.Flow.authorizationCodeWithPKCE.callback (http://localhost:4200/packages/openid_client/src/http_util.dart.lib.js:831:21)

at callback.next (<anonymous>)

at runBody (http://localhost:4200/dart_sdk.js:40317:34)

at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:4200/dart_sdk.js:40353:7)

at openid.Flow.authorizationCodeWithPKCE.callback (http://localhost:4200/packages/openid_client/src/http_util.dart.lib.js:829:20)

at XXX_bloc.XXXBloc.new.authenticateWeb (http://localhost:4200/packages/fo_xfel/screens/staff_application/staff_application.dart.lib.js:7289:41)

at authenticateWeb.next (<anonymous>)

at http://localhost:4200/dart_sdk.js:40298:33

at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:4200/dart_sdk.js:40169:59)

at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:4200/dart_sdk.js:35563:29)

at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:4200/dart_sdk.js:36151:49)

at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:4200/dart_sdk.js:36189:17)

at [_complete] (http://localhost:4200/dart_sdk.js:36022:25)

at http://localhost:4200/dart_sdk.js:35019:30

at internalCallback (http://localhost:4200/dart_sdk.js:26826:11)
```